# How does keyDown() Method in libGDX work properly?

Tags: java, libgdx, keydown

I recently started coding in Java with libGDX. Now I tried to do a small cutscene, (a background-image appears, then an Actor floats in from the left, the Actor talks!), and there is the problem: All things are working just fine, except the key Input, to forwarding the Dialog. So the first Dialog-Box appears and to continue, you have to press the 'C' key, then there should appear the second message and then after an Second 'C'-press, the Actor should dissapear and the Game should start.

Here is the code for the Overriden keyDown()-Method:

```
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keyCode) {
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.C))
        if(continueKey.isVisible())
            scene.loadNextSegment();
    return false;
}
```

the class looks as following:

```
public class StoryScreen extends BaseScreen {
```

and the BaseScreen class:

```
public abstract class BaseScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor {
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards DKJ1337!

Edit: If I do the Input handling inside the update Method of the StoryScreen class, then it works but it just skips the whole second part of the Dialog.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Corrected** (as original answer was downvoted) after some investigation in comments:

Make sure the thing that implements `InputProcessor` is registered with `Input.setInputProcessor(InputProcessor)`.

Described in more details here [libgdx wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling)

---

**Wrong answer**

Try to `return true` when the event should be processed by the `InputProcessor`

e.g.:

```
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keyCode) {
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.C))
        if(continueKey.isVisible()) {
            scene.loadNextSegment();
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Well I tried that already but that didn`t work as well but thanks for your answer.

Comment: No worries. You sure that part `continueKey.isVisible()` returns true? If you remove the second `if` statement and printout something to console, will it pop there when you press 'C'?

Comment: Well that´s a good question thanks i´l try it and be right back thanks.

Comment: So i tried it and there is no output neither if I remove the second if nor if only the 'C' key is pressed.

Comment: Is the first `if` even gets called? Try to move the output line to the line right below the `keyDown(int...)`. Alternatively, use debug breakpoints. Just to check that it ever triggered

Comment: So even that isn´t working -.- The keyDow()-Method never gets triggered. But I don´t know why the keyDown()-Method didn´t do anything!

Comment: Have you registered your InputProcessor (in your case `StoryScreen`)? By doing `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this)` from, say, `StoryScreen`'s `create()` method or constructor?

Comment: Well thank you that worked. But I don´t really understand why the InputProcessor from the BaseScreen class isn´t getting over but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call Gdx.input.setInputProcessor() somewhere?

By the way, there are other problems in your code:

```
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keyCode) {
    if(keyCode == Input.Keys.C)
        if(continueKey.isVisible()) {
            scene.loadNextSegment();
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Compare to the given keycode, and return true when you've done something.